# logo change procedure doesn't seem to work

Tags: plone

I upload a new logo.jpg in the ZMI: /portal_skins/plone_images/logo.jpg.  hit save and see the new image in the preview, but it doesn't show up in the top left  corner of the site. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you're on plone 4, the default skin uses "logo.png" not "logo.jpg"

Comment: Comment by [spliter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/191426/spliter): Also make sure to empty your browser's cache (`Shift` + `F5` button) after you change the logo.